# Unable to deploy an ERC 720 token in Mumbai Test says insufficient funds

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, matic

I was trying to deploy an ERC 721 token using truffle in Polygon's mumbai testnet.
And i have 2.8296 Matic in my metasmask wallet which i got from their faucet. But when i try to  run

```
truffle migrate --network matic
```

it says

```
Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  0x12aADAdd301d22c941DACF2cfa7A9e2019972F61
   * Balance:  0 wei
   * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
   * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.
```

Am i doing something wrong? What sould be the gas and gas price i should mention in truffle config file.
Here is my truffle-config file

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
      port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
      network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
    matic: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(process.env.MNEMONIC, `https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/v1/91fdbb5c2f37c699621ss7d2b8b127fc1a123060
      `),
      network_id: 80001,
      confirmations: 2,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
  },

  // Set default mocha options here, use special reporters etc.
  mocha: {
    // timeout: 100000
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwpLO.png)

I am pretty sure there is no balance of this account 0x12aADAdd301d22c941DACF2cfa7A9e2019972F61 in Mumbai-Testnet

Comment: Yeah i figured out i have several accounts with my mumbai test net in the metamask. And the one which has the balance is not being used.